# Module.exports and es6 Import

Tags: javascript, babeljs, es6-module-loader

React with babel. I have this confusion with imports and module.exports. I assume babel when converting the ES6 code to ES5 converts the imports and exports to require and module.exports respectively.

If I export a function from one module and import the function in another module, the code executes fine. But if I export the function with module.exports and import using "import" the error is thrown at runtime saying it is not a function.

I cooked up an example.

```js
// Tiger.js
function Tiger() {
    function roar(terrian){
        console.log('Hey i am in ' +  terrian + ' and i am roaing');
    };
    return roar;
}

module.exports = Tiger;

// animal.js
import { Tiger } from './animals';

var animal = Tiger();
animal("jungle");
```

I used babel with preset es2015 to transcompile it. This gives me the following error

> *Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _animals.Tiger) is not a function*

But if I remove the `module.exports = Tiger;` And replace it with `export { Tiger };` It works fine.

What am I missing here??

**EDIT:**
I am using browserify as the module bundler.

Comment: Have you looked at the Babel output? Looking at the transpiled source of `Tiger.js` will tell you immediately why it's not working. Long story short: stick with one module system or use a module bundler like webpack that will take care of inconsistencies.

Comment: Sorry to mention i am using browserify as the module bundler

Answer (score 77):

`export { Tiger }` would be equivalent to `module.exports.Tiger = Tiger`.

Conversely, `module.exports = Tiger` would be equivalent to `export default Tiger`.

So when you use `module.exports = Tiger` and then attempt `import { Tiger } from './animals'` you're effectively asking for `Tiger.Tiger`.

Comment: so what would the correct import statement be here?  would it just be `import Tiger from './animals'`?

Comment: I believe so, assuming you didn't want to change tiger.js

Answer (score 50):

If you would like to import:

```
module.exports = Tiger
```

you may use following construction:

```
import * as Tiger from './animals'
```

Then it will work.

Another option is changing the export as described by @Matt Molnar but it is only possible if you are the author of the imported code.

Comment: The `import * as Tiger from './animals'` work for me ! Thank you

Comment: `Tiger` is a function in the example above. You can't import callable (function or class) using `import * as something`, because `something` will be representing a `namespace` object, which is not callable. The correct import for this case would be the default import: `import Tiger from './animals';`.

Answer (score 24):

When `module.exports` is not set it points to an empty object (`{}`). When you do `module.exports = Tiger`, you are telling the runtime the object being exported from that module is the `Tiger` object (instead of the default `{}`), which in this case is a function.
Since you want to import that same function, the way to import is using the default import (`import tiger from './tiger'`). Otherwise, if you want to use named import (`import { tiger } from './tiger'`) you must change the `module.exports` object or use `export` keyword instead of `module.exports` object.

Default import/export:

```
// tiger.js
module.exports = tiger;
// or
export default function tiger() { ... }

// animal.js
import tiger from './tiger';
```

Named import/export:

```
// tiger.js
module.exports = { tiger };
// or
module.exports.tiger = tiger
// or
export const tiger = () => { ... }
// or
export function tiger() => { ... }

// animal.js
import { tiger } from './tiger';
```

Comment: add some explanation to your answer

Comment: Yeah, my bad. My answer was just to add some more solutions besides what was already explained.

Comment: Good and self explanatory examples. Thanks a lot for making it easy to understand