# How can I export all functions from a file in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a unit converter, and I want to put all of the conversion functions into their own file. Using ES6 `export`, is there any way to export all of the functions in the file with their default names using only one line? For example:

`export default all;`

The functions are all just in the file, not within an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 export all values from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844074/es6-export-all-values-from-object)

Comment: @Hamms: Except the OP doesn't have an object, so...

Comment: I'd consider exporting an Object containing all the functions: `export default { fn1(), fn2(), ... }`, or wrapping them inside a `class` then `export default MyClass`. One other solution is to put `export` in front of every functions and `import * as MyConverter from './myconverter.js'`

Answer (score 132, accepted):

No, there's no wildcard export (except when you're *re-exporting* everything from another module, but that's not what you're asking about).

Simply put `export` in front of each function declaration you want exported, e.g.

```
export function foo() {
    // ...
}
export function bar() {
    // ...
}
```

...or of course, if you're using function expressions:

```
export var foo = function() {
    // ...
};
export let bar = () => {
    // ...
};
export const baz = value => {
    // ...
};
```

Comment: You can search and replace `^function` with `export function`

Answer (score 65):

I think there are a lot of solutions to this. And as has been answered, there's no wildcard export. But, you can 'wildcard' the import. So, I much prefer the one putting `export` before each of the functions you want to expose from the file:

```
//myfile.js
export function fn1() {...} 
export function fn2() {...}
```

and then `import` it like so:

```
import * as MyFn from './myfile.js'
```

Afterwards you could use it like so:

```
MyFn.fn1();
MyFn.fn2();
```

Comment: First I thought very nice, then I can also export and import my "global" variables. Unfortunately the imported things are read-only. I don't know why, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/58402982/1707015 has found a remedy.

Comment: This worked in my case but I wasn't able to run the file without adding "type": "module", in my packege.json.

Comment: @moghwan Note that you need `"type": "module"` in package.json when you're using pure NodeJS.

Answer (score 31):

You can also use `module.exports` as follows:

```
function myFunction(arg) {
  console.debug(arg);
}
function otherFunction(arg) {
  console.error(arg);
}

module.exports = {
  myFunction: myFunction,
  otherFunction: otherFunction,
};
```

Then you can import it:

```
import {myFunction, otherFunction} from "./Functions.js";
```

Comment: You don't need to write out the names twice.  just module.exports  ={myFunction,otherFunction} will work just the same.

Comment: yes, this is true, i was just showing you could write it to also export "myrandofunc" as "thisisabettername_forthefunction" although then i don't why you wouldn't just rename the function anyway! lmao @ me - sometimes i like being pedantic? but yes thanks!

Comment: what if i want to export all the functions in a file with `module.exports = { func1, func2, func3 }` and I want to import them all? what should I write? `import * from '../myfile.js'` does not work...

Comment: @Don Diego, I am not sure about import. This question was about exporting functions.

Answer (score 25):

In my use case, I do have three reusable functions in one file.

**utils/reusables.js**

```
export const a = () => {}
export const b = () => {}
export const c = () => {}
```

In order to point the root folder instead of individual file names, I created a file called `index.js` which will comprise of all the functions that are listed in individual files.

**utils/index.js**

```
export * from './reusables'
```

Now, when I want to use my `a` function, I will have to simply import it like this

```
import { a } from '../utils'
```

Rather than calling it from its individual files

```
import { a } from '../utils/reusables'
```

Comment: Are you sure this `export a = () => {}` works? I get `Declaration or statement expected.`

Comment: @Qwerty Looks like I forgot to add `const` keyword. Let me update my answer. But, this should work. 
`export const a = () => {}`

Answer (score 11):

You could also export them at the bottom of your script.

```
function cube(x) {
  return x * x * x;
}

const foo = Math.PI + Math.SQRT2;

var graph = {
  options: {
      color:'white',
      thickness:'2px'
  },
  draw: function() {
      console.log('From graph draw function');
  }
}

export { cube, foo, graph };
```

You can also aggregate submodules together in a parent module so that they are available to import from that module.

```
// In parentModule.js
export { myFunction, myVariable } from 'childModule1.js';
export { myClass } from 'childModule2.js';

// In top-level module
import { myFunction, myVariable, myClass } from 'parentModule.js'
```

Answer (score 9):

I think there's a missing common solution, which is exporting in `index.js` file:

`myModule/myFunctions.js`

```
export const foo = () => { ... }
export const bar = () => { ... }
```

then in `myModule/index.js`

```
export * from "./myFunctions.js";
```

This way you can simply import and use it with:

```
import { foo, bar } from "myModule";
foo();
bar();
```

Answer (score 6):

For `Node.js` environment, what I did to export functions was this.

**UserController.js**

```
module.exports = {
  signUp: () => {
    return "user"
  },
  login: () => {
    return "login"
  }
}
```

**UserRouter.js**

```
const UserController = require('./UserController')
```

then `login` and `signUp` functions could be used inside `UserRouter` as `UserController.signUp()` and `UserController.login()`

Comment: Actually, how can we use that workaround with import and not require?

Comment: Node below v12 doesn't support es6 import/export. However you will be able to use this in other places. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278474/module-exports-and-es6-import

Comment: Or, something along the lines of `exports.signUp = () => "user"` can also work

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone still needs an answer to this in modern JavaScript:

```
const hello = () => "hello there"
const bye = () => "bye bye"
export default { hello, bye }
```

Answer (score 2):

**functions.js**

```
function alpha(msj) {
    console.log('In alpha: ' + msj);
}

function beta(msj) {
    console.log('In beta: ' + msj);
}

module.exports = {
    alpha,
    beta
};
```

**main.js**

```
const functions = require('./functions');
functions.alpha('Hi');
functions.beta('Hello');
```

**Run**

```
node main.js
```

**Output**

```
In alpha: Hi
In beta: Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is to export all functions within an object:

```
//File.js
 
export default {

    testFunction1: function testFunction1(){
        console.log("Hello World")  
    },
    //a little bit cleaner
    testFunction2: () => {
        console.log("Nothing here")
    }

}
```

Now you can access the functions with calling the key value of the object:

```
//differentFile.js

import file from 'File.js'

file.testFunction1()
//Hello World

file.testFunction2()
//Nothing here
```