# Globally imported variables are undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three variables in my **FinalVariables.js** as follows :

```
var finalTaskName = 'abc'
var finalQuantityTaskExecuted = 0
var finalQuantityTaskCompletion = 100

export {finalTaskName, finalQuantityTaskExecuted, finalQuantityTaskCompletion}
```

In another file, I am importing them using the following line:

```
import {finalTaskName,finalQuantityTaskExecuted,finalQuantityTaskCompletion} from './FinalVariables'
```

However when I try to use any of the above three variables in the other file, they're always `undefined`. 
Is there a reason for this?

I am new to Javascript and React and any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Updated-------------------------------------------------------------

I imported the variables as follows :

```
import * as finalVariables from './FinalVariables'
```

When I do a 
`console.log(finalVariables.finalTaskName)`

I'm able to print the correct value, but when I try to assign a value to it :

```
finalVariables.finalTaskName = this.props.item[0].particulars
```

I'm getting the following error :

> Cannot set property finalTaskName of # which has only a getter

============================= Updated ======================================

I am able to update the values correctly now but in the main class TasksInsert.jsx where I am importing these values, I have this in the render function,

```
<p>{finalVariables.finalTaskName}</p> 
<p>{finalVariables.finalQuantityTaskExecuted}</p> 
<p>{finalVariables.finalQuantityTaskCompletion}</p>
```

Why are these values not reflecting according to the recent changes? My state constructor looks like this :

```
this.setState({ finalVariables })
```

--------------------------------------------------------------------- Updated --------------------------------------

I followed a similar approach for a global array called BOQSuggestions, to which I was pushing data and it worked, that is changes to it were reflected globally.

Plus, this is the only place I will be needing shared data, which is why I don't want to use Redux.

Could anyone please suggest code to fix this issue? I am still stuck here and am new to Javascript.

Comment: export default?

Comment: If I do that , I get the message 'Attempted import error: 'finalQuantityTaskCompletion' is not exported from './FinalVariables''

Comment: Could you share more of your code , just to check.

Comment: you can try `import * as someVars from './FinalVariables';` and `console.log(someVars);` to see what you're importing

Comment: I imported the variables as follows : 

import * as finalVariables from './FinalVariables'


When I do a 

console.log(finalVariables.finalTaskName)

I'm able to print the correct value, but when I try to assign a value to it :


finalVariables.finalTaskName = this.props.item[0].particulars


I'm getting the following error : 


Cannot set property finalTaskName of #<Object> which has only a getter

Comment: Why are you trying to set values to your imports?

Comment: You can `export default {finalTaskName, finalQuantityTaskExecuted, finalQuantityTaskCompletion}` and then `import finalVariables from './FinalVariables'`. You shouldn't reassign them though, that's what that error means. If you need a mutable object, import a class or a factory function which generate a new object every time, or set it at the start of your app and pass it down.

Comment: I want to be able to access these values throughout my file across all components, so I am importing them globally. @SrThompson, could you please suggest the code for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Module exports are readonly by design. If you want some global mutable state, you should do so by exporting a mutable object from a module:

```
// final-vars.js

export default {
  finalTaskName: 'abc', 
  finalQuantityTaskExecuted: 0, 
  finalQuantityTaskCompletion: 100
};
```

```
// other.js

import finalVariables from './final-vars';

// ...

finalVariables.finalTaskName = this.props.item[0].particulars // Allowed
```

Comment: Thank you @Jacob. I am able to update the values correctly now but in the main class TasksInsert.jsx where I am importing these values, I have this in the render function, 


<p>{finalVariables.finalTaskName}</p> 
<p>{finalVariables.finalQuantityTaskExecuted}</p>
<p>{finalVariables.finalQuantityTaskCompletion}</p>

Why are these values not reflecting according to the recent changes? My state constructor looks like this : 


this.setState({
            finalVariables,
            
        })

Comment: Your expectation is that if something else changes these variables that your UI will respond to those changes? JavaScript doesn't quite work that way. I don't think mutable global variables are the way for you to go here. If you want your UI to respond to variable changes, then you need something you can _subscribe_ to.

Comment: For shared state that React can respond to, that's what solutions like `redux` and context are for.

Comment: I followed a similar approach for a global array called BOQSuggestions, to which I was pushing data and it worked, that is changes to it were reflected globally. 

Plus, this is the only place I will be needing shared data, which is why I don't want to use Redux. Could anyone please suggest code to fix this issue? I am still stuck here and am new to Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function in `FinalVariables.js` file as:

```js
const setFinalTaskName = (value)=>finalTaskName=value
```

Export and call it from your component as:

```js
setFinalTaskName(--new-value--)
```