# How to import a file that already imports another file?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, visual-studio-code

Javascript, ES6. I have three files:

*inline-functions.js*

```
\*
    Bunch of small functions.
*/
```

*some-module.js*

```
import './inline-functions.js'

// uses many inline functions
```

*main.js*

```
import './inline-functions.js'
import './some-module.js'

// uses inline functions as well as classes from some-module.js
```

Now, I use Visual Studio Code and I would like Intellisense working but when I am editing `main.js`, it only shows functions from `inline-functions.js` and everything from 'some-module.js' is unreachable even though there is an import statement. However, when I comment the import out of `some-module.js` like this:

```
// import './inline-functions.js'
// tries to use inline functions which are now not callable
```

Intellisense suddenly shows correct names and documentation for all objects. This is of course unusable because `some-module.js` now can't call any of the inline functions.

What is the correct way of importing these modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the module function only if you export it from the module.

Export the function form the module then you will see it in main js.

**Example:**

some-module.js

```
import './inline-functions.js'

const someFuncion1 = () =>  1;
const someFuncion2 = () => 2;

export {
    someFuncion1,
    someFuncion2
}
```

main.js

```
import * as inline './inline-functions.js'
import * as some './some-module.js'

//Access it like 

inline.<function name>
some.<function name>
```

Comment: I looked up `export` and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49616670/10732434). Sadly there is no wildcard export and I have to tag each function or put them in bracket export like in your answer.