# Can you import a function from a react component into a test file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Is there a way to import a function from a react component into a test file?

for example:

component:

```
const funcToExport = () => {
      let a = 1;
      let b = 2;
      let value = a + b;
      return value
}
```

test file:

```
import funcToExport from './component';
```

can this be done, so you can use the function in the test file?

Comment: you can read about  import/export [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616639/how-can-i-export-all-functions-from-a-file-in-js) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616639/how-can-i-export-all-functions-from-a-file-in-js) can helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the keyword "export" to your function then import it in other files.
There are two different types of export:

**Named Export:**

```
export const funcToExport = () => {
      let a = 1;
      let b = 2;
      let value = a + b;
      return value
}
```

Import:

```
import { funcToExport } from "/file-path"
```

**Default Export**

```
const funcToExport = () => {
      let a = 1;
      let b = 2;
      let value = a + b;
      return value
}
export default funcToExport;
```

Import:

```
import funcToExport from "/file-path"
```

For more info check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: just an addon, you will need to import it like ```import {funcToExport} from './component';```