# What is the import statement equivalent of require('./app/routes/posts.routes.js')(app)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've tried different ways to search for this and I am coming up with nothing. When setting up an express app and importing a file of routes you often see documentation for this statement:

```
require('./app/routes/posts.routes.js')(app)
```

Which from the documentation in [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/) means to require the file './app/routes/posts.routes.js' and run everything in the app object.

What I have not come across is how to write this statement using "import".

### My example:

**Route File Contents**

```
module.exports = (app) => {

    import posts from '../controllers/post.controller.js'

    app.post('/posts', posts.create);

    app.get('/posts', posts.findAll);

    app.get('/posts/:postId', posts.findOne);

    app.put('/posts/:postId', posts.update);

    app.delete('/posts/:postId', notes.delete);
}
```

**Import Statement**

```
//this does not work throws Error: Cannot find package 'app' imported from /Users/matt1/socialbulk/server/server.js

import posts from 'app/routes/post.routes.js' //what do you do with (app)?

app.use('/posts', posts) 

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
});
```

### Thank you so much in advance for your help!!!!

Comment: Try using `../`,`./` or `/` as first characters of the import path.

Comment: Your "*Route File Contents*" is an invalid mixture of `module.exports` and `import` syntax. What does the file actually look like?

Comment: @Bergi the file has been shared and `import` is backward compatible with `module.exports` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278474/module-exports-and-es6-import

Comment: @MaximeHelen The shared code snippet is just a plain syntax error. And the backward compatibility depends on your module loader, it should not be assumed generally.

Comment: @Bergi So it depends on the v8 engine version? Is there a compatibility table somewhere that confirms the flakiness on that side?

Comment: @MaximeHelen I said module loader (which often means transpiler/bundler), not js engine. (Notice that only ES6 modules are standardised, the rest is always platform-dependent). If you're talking about node.js specifically, see https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_interoperability_with_commonjs.

Comment: @Bergi Ah I wasn't aware of the synonyms, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`module.exports = foo` is equivalent to `export default foo`

Here `foo` is a function

```
import posts from 'app/routes/post.routes.js' //what do you do with (app)?

app.use('/posts', posts(app)) 

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: An explanation on why this works would be nice. It's not immediately clear what you modified.

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup Done!